# Node.js options for http.get

Tags: node.js, http, get

So I'm just starting with node.js, and am not quite sure how to proceed with an assignment for school. The assignment is setting up a basic server that sends data from a .json file to the page when a get request is sent.

```
//Your request handler should send listingData in the JSON format if a GET 
//request is sent to the '/listings' path. Otherwise, it should send a 404 
//error.

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
  var parsedUrl = url.parse(request.url);
  **more code**};
```

I played around with creating an if/else statement so that if the parsedUrl.pathname matched /listings, then it will pipe the desired data from the .json file. It works fine like this, but I think we need to use the http.get function. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to set up the options so that the host is the localhost, and not some other website. I've been watching tutorials and I think I can figure the rest out, but nothing I've seen or read has helped with the 'options' part.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const http = require('http');
const MYJSON = require('./myJson')// path to your json file
http.createServer((request, response) => {
  if (request.method === 'GET' && request.url === '/') {

    response.end(JSON.stringify(MYJSON));
  } else {
    response.statusCode = 404;
    response.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```